# Get sensor_msgs/LaserScan message from simulation(v-rep)

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello all,

is it possible to use LMS1xx package, but get the messages from simulation(eg. in vrep) instead of the real laser scanner?

Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/83111/get-sensor_msgs/laserscan-message-from-simulation(v-rep)/) by [Yami](https://answers.ros.org/users/6274/yami/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-09-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It should work. I have worked with simulated Hokoyu laser scanners, in vrep, then exported the data from vrep as pointcloud into ROS, then used pointcloud_to_laserscan package to output a scan

---

Originally posted by [achuwilson](https://answers.ros.org/users/1658/achuwilson/) with karma: 128 on 2013-09-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Yami](https://answers.ros.org/users/6274/yami/) on 2013-09-25**:
Nice, but is it not so that the pointcloud_to_laserscan package changes 3D point clouds to LaserScan messages? I also get point clouds from v-rep, but from a 2d laser scanner. Can u plz help me with that?
Thanks